# magento 2 how to override product views report for custom admin report

Tags: magento2, admin, custom, reports

Please tell me all the steps to override product view report in my custom module, i am new in magento so i don't know how to do that, thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can override product view report in your custom module using following way:

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */ 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="2.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

Create Custom menu on admin side.

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::view" title="Product Views Report" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="50" resource="Vendor_Module::view"/>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::menu" title="Product Views Report" module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="20" parent="Vendor_Module::view" action="reports/report_product/viewed" resource="Vendor_Module::menu"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Override "reports_report_product_viewed.xml" in your custom module.

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/reports_report_product_viewed.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" template="Magento_Backend::store/switcher.phtml" name="store.switcher">
                <action method="setStoreVarName">
                    <argument name="var_name" xsi:type="string">store_ids</argument>
                </action>
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="switch_websites" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    <argument name="switch_store_groups" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    <argument name="switch_store_views" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    <argument name="default_selection_name" xsi:type="string" translate="true">All Websites Override</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock  name="grid.filter.form">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::views_report/view.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In above "reports_report_product_viewed.xml" file I have changed "switch_websites" and "switch_store_groups" from "1 to 0", after that it'll disable "websites and store groups" from store switcher and also changed "default_selection_name"/ store switcher text from "All Websites to All Websites Override" and also change content part using call custom template file as you can see in screenshot.[image]

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: where to change action of show report button and also make change template file

Comment: You can override block of Reports in your custom module for changing in action and template file => "Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Viewed"